# The block "yoast-seo/related-links"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, block, yoast

I have received this error on the console but I have not found details on google ...

what is wrong?

should this script be used?
And for what purpose?

Does this blockage affect other aspects of the site?

### console error message

```
 The block yoast-seo/related-links is registered with an invalid category "yoast-internal-linking-blocks".
```

### name file>>>  blocks.min.js

Comment: Hi @Paulo, It seems like yoast-seo configuration related problem. It's really hard to give the correct answer with just the info above. Please share more details. You can DM me and I'm willing to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Back up the extension and database

right after the SEO extension should be removed, as well as any additions to it.

clear your site's cache, as well as your browser's cache, along with cookies.

check the page's source code to see if the extension's javascript script was found. if so, clearing the cache and cookies didn’t work. in this case, repeat the process.

if you have problems with this step. try this check in another browser.

If JavaScript was not found in the source code, the cache was successfully cleared.

after this confirmation, install the extension.
It is worth mentioning to pay attention to the latest version.
also install add-ons that were previously deleted
go to the extension backup and import to a new installation.

this should ensure that this error information does not appear again.

check the settings, as well as in incognito display the error on the console. Positive case. uninstalled the plugin and installed it again.

Answer (score 1):

check the settings, as well as in incognito display the error on the console. Positive case. uninstalled the plugin and installed it again.